# How to insert multiple values from checkbox group in oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, oracle-apex

I have an order table(id_order,id_category) and category table(id_category,description).
How can I insert to an order, more than 1 type of category in oracle Apex app?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a shuttle item; it'll let you easily move desired categories from its left to right side. The result is a semi-colon separated list of values. For example, if you chose categories 1, 5 and 7, result is `1;5;7` so - in order to insert them *properly* into the `order` table, you'll first have to split them to rows.

How? Use `apex_string.split`:

```
SQL> select * from table(apex_string.split('1;5;7', ';'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
5
7

SQL>
```

All rows would share the same `order_id`, I presume (a sequence might be a good choice for its value).

Comment: Is there any possibility to insert only one row into the order table, with the values of id_category concatenated?

Comment: Sure, but that violates the 3rd normal form so you should avoid it.